# Will_Paginate NoMethodError (undefined method `paginate'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to in the "will_paginate" gem however when I push it to Heroku, I get the following error message on the Heroku server. The solution works perfectly in my development in environment.

```
2015-11-06T18:34:43.422821+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by AccountsController#index as HTML
        2015-11-06T18:34:43.509289+00:00 app[web.1]: 
        2015-11-06T18:34:43.509292+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `paginate' for #<Account::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f39bc853bd8>):
        2015-11-06T18:34:43.509293+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:8:in `index'
        2015-11-06T18:34:43.509294+00:00 app[web.1]: 
        2015-11-06T18:34:43.509295+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Accounts Controller:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_account, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @account = Account.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8)
  end

  def show
    @notes = Note.where(account_id: @account.id) #Where a note belong to the current account
  end

  def new
    @account = Account.new
    respond_with(@account)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    @account.save
    respond_with(@account)
  end

  def update
    @account.update(account_params)
    respond_with(@account)
  end

  def destroy
    @account.destroy
    respond_with(@account)
  end

  private
    def set_account
      @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    end

    def account_params
      params.require(:account).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :return_client, :program_id, :insurance_id, :address, :phone)
    end
end
```

Index.html.erb

```
<br>
<%= will_paginate @account , renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
<br>
<%= link_to 'Add Client', new_account_path %>
```

Gem File
 source 'http://rubygems.org'

```
ruby '2.1.5'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'pg', group: :production
gem 'carrierwave'
gem "fog"
gem "figaro"
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
gem 'execjs'
gem "mini_magick"
gem 'devise'
gem 'searchkick'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
end
```

Then gem env is the same on both servers. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Can you show your `Gemfile`? Would like to see how you have added `will_paginate` gem in there. You basically need to make sure that the gem is installed on heroku properly.

Comment: If you are sure that `will_paginate` gem installed properly on heroku and still you are getting the above error, try requiring it in your `AccountsController `: `require 'will_paginate'`

Comment: The issue is that `will_paginate` is in the development and test groups only this means when Heroku bundles production it is not included. Thus `NoMethodError`. Move `will_paginate` out of the group definitions and it should work fine

Comment: @engineersmnky that was exactly the problem. Once I move will_paginate out of those groups into production, it worked.

Comment: Cheers. Hope you learned something. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'` from `group :development, :test do` to  `gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0', group: :production` and that corrected the NoMethodError message in the Heroku log.